# How can I implement the multi-level list in drupal7 with theme_item_list()?

Tags: list, drupal, themes, drupal-7, multi-level

Im using drupal 7, I would like to know whether i can use the function theme_item_list() to implement multi-level list items. As below:

Item 1

  test
- Item 1.1
- Item 1.2
- Item 1.3

Item 2

- Item 2.1
- Item 2.2
- Item 2.3

  - Item 2.3.1
  - Item 2.3.2
  - Item 2.3.3

Item 3

If possible can anybody help me with an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible, if you pass in an array with keys of `data` and `children` for each item that has a sub-list, for example:

```
$items = array(
  array(
    'data' => 'Item 1',
    'children' => array(
      array(
        'data' => 'Item 1.1',
        'children' => array(
          'Item 1.1.1',
          'Item 1.1.2'
        )
      ),
      array(
        'data' => 'Item 1.2',
        'children' => array(
          'Item 1.2.1',
          'Item 1.2.2'
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  array(
    'data' => 'Item 2',
    'children' => array(
      // etc...
    )
  )
);

$output = theme('item_list', array('items' => $items));
```

The `data` key represents the contents of the list item, `children` is an array of list items to render as a separate list within that list item. The function is recursive and can handle any number of levels.

Comment: Thanks. Note that instead of calling `theme()` directly it's often better to build a render array like this: `$output = array( '#theme' => 'item_list', '#items' => $items, '#type' => 'ul', );`

Comment: Absolutely right @marcvangend, I think this answer pre-dated the whole shift to render arrays :)